# Issue with using decodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, html, decodeuricomponent

Im trying to decode the %20 in the URL link so that i cant get my value without adding %20 in the textfield when i decode the code from current page to next page, below is my coding for decode the %20 and where i place

```
function loadRecord(i){
    var item=dataset.item(i);
    fname.value = item['fname'];
    id.value = item['id'];
    window.location.href = decodeURIComponent("userup2.html?id="+item['id']+"&fname="+item['fname']+"&val=300");
    return false;
}
```

This is the current and will redirect to second page to display the data

[image]

[image]

why it still display the %20 even though i code the decodeURIComponent? please help

Comment: What programming language do you use to construct your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode the URI when it's passed to your input. Decoding it to pass it to `window.location` is correct, but the browser will escape it again.

I assume you take the input value from the params. So where you set the input value from the params (in your case, certainly in the document `userup2.html`, you have to decode the URI.

So where you set the input value from the params, you have to decode it again:

```
document.getElementByTagName('input').value = decodeURI(...your code to get the params);
```

Comment: thanks alot man, finally i can decode the %20, thanks again!! =)

Answer (score 0):

> why it still display the %20 even though i code the decodeURIComponent?

Browser is encoding the url to make it a valid URL. Even though you are decoding it, its again assigned to window.location.href, so the control is back to browser.

You cannot bypass it. Instead decode the url at the receiving end.